# How do you derive the integrating factor formula for first order linear ODEs?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

The Cauchy problem for a given First-Order linear ODE
$$
\begin{cases}
y' + p(x)y = f(x), \\
y(x_0) = y_0
\end{cases}
$$
can be solved by the standard "variation of parameters" formula
$$
y(x) = e^{-\int_{x_0}^x p(s)\,ds} \left(\int_{x_0}^x e^{\int_{x_0}^t p(s)\,ds} f(t)\,dt + y_0 \right).\label{1}\tag{eq:17}
$$
See for example [math.libretexts](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/1%3A_First_order_ODEs/1.4%3A_Linear_equations_and_the_integrating_factor#mjx-eqn-eq%3A17), exercise 1.4.1..

I don't understand how to derive \eqref{1}. I believe that I need to use a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\frac d{dx}\int_a^xf(t)=f(x)\implies \int_a^xf(t)=\int f(x)dx.
$$

But I am struggling with how they are getting that exact form. In particular, how are they getting the $y_0$ term inside the brackets? And how are they getting $x_0$ and $x$ as the bounds of integration? rather than some arbitrary $a$ as the lower bound and $x_0$ as the upper bounds (as suggested by FTC). Furthermore, how are they/why can they bring the initial conditions into the bounds of the integral? Could someone please walk me through the full working?

Comment: The term integrating factor is misleading. What you have is an inhomogeneous first order linear ODE. Write that solution in the form $y(x)=u(x)v(x)$ and use the product rule to see that it solves. The term $y_0$ inside the parenthesis is dictated by $y(0)=y_0\,.$

Comment: Typo: by $y(x_0)=y_0\,.$

Comment: The integral on the right is indefinite so it produces a constant term. Then what happens when $x=x_0$?